# How can I get the issue id from within a Jira plugin Webwork actions template?

Tags: java, jira-plugin

I am writing a Jira 5 plugin. I have a web action mapped to a velocity template. The action is triggered from a link generated by a web-item. My question is: how can I insert the issue key/id into my template? I tried:

$issue, $issue.id

I tried to extend `AbstractIssueSelectAction` but its `getIssueObject()` throws exception saying that the issue id/key is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link, that invokes the action (for example "SampleAction"), must be like this:
http://something.com/app/context/SampleAction.jspa?id=${issue.id}
Just like bundled JIRA actions do.

Assuming that you're extending AbstractIssueSelectAction you can simply use ${action.id} in your result pages if you want to re-submit this ID.